# Multiple data-rel values

Tags: jquery, datarelation

I have multiple objects with data-rel values and for only some of them I would like to be able to, let's say, change to color of the content to red like so:

**HTML**

```
<p data-rel="1">1</p>
<p data-rel="2">2</p>
<p data-rel="3">3</p>
<p data-rel="4">4</p>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 $("[data-rel='1'], [data-rel='3']").hover(function (){
        $( this ).css({
            'color': 'red'
        });
    });
```

This works but it can get pretty boring to write for each value `[data-rel='3']` so I was wondering, is there a way to do this something like: `[data-rel='1, 3']` instead of `[data-rel='1'], [data-rel='3']`?

Comment: Wouldn't giving them a common class be the easiest solution?

Comment: If there's a sequence, yes it can be done.

Comment: @j08691 It would but I actually need them different since each data-rel is tied to another function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have a cool way of doing it

```
var arr = [1, 3]; // add the numbers you want
$('[data-rel]').filter(function(x) {
    return arr.indexOf(+$(this).data("rel")) > -1; // check if it is present
}).hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Well, with some work this would do but the thing is that I wanted less code, simplified, I will have more pairs of less or equal to 4 numbers, nu more, so this solution would only make my script longer

Comment: @Alin well, all you've to do is add numbers to the array

Comment: @Alin - I doubt you'd get much shorter than this.

Comment: Well yes, I agree with you that I would only have to add numbers to the array, but I have 63 such objects that will be in pairs of 4, If one of those 4 is hovered, all of them react. With 63 objects I would have to write the code above 16 times, so this would actually make it longer than the original solution ^^ But Thanks a lot. +1 for your time and the idea :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the odd numbered ones only, you could do it as follows:

```
$('[data-rel]').filter(function(i,p) { 
    return +$(p).data('rel') % 2 === 1;
})
.hover(function() {
    $( this ).css({
        'color': 'red'
    });
});
```

```js
$('[data-rel]').filter(function(i,p) { 
    return +$(p).data('rel') % 2 === 1;
})
.hover(function() {
    $( this ).css({
        'color': 'red'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-rel="1">1</p>
<p data-rel="2">2</p>
<p data-rel="3">3</p>
<p data-rel="4">4</p>
```

Comment: Well, not quite, I have more than 4 and it will be mixed numbers. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Is there a sequence to it? Or are you able to pre-determine which these are?

Comment: I am able to pre-determine them.

Comment: Unfortunately without some kind of a formular or list, I can only help so much.

Comment: Well, it's fine, I just wanted to see if there's an easier way of doing it, I didn't want to write so much and make my code longer than it has to be. +1 For your example. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I believe @AmitJoki has the right idea; listing all the number you want affected and using that in the event handler.